# Possible phishing?

Tags: discussion, support

Just received this email "from" Stack Overflow:

[image]

Relevant Headers:

```
Received: from o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net (o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net [168.245.32.199])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by in-003.mia.mailroute.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 46k2Cl25H6z23jS1
    for <obfuscated@obfuscated.com>; Wed,  2 Oct 2019 16:49:06 +0000 (UTC)
Authentication-Results: mail.mailroute.net; dmarc=pass (p=reject dis=none) header.from=stackoverflow.email
Authentication-Results: mail.mailroute.net; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=bounces+5841141-c769-obfuscated=obfuscated.com@em.stackoverflow.email
Authentication-Results: mail.mailroute.net;
    dkim=pass (1024-bit key) header.d=stackoverflow.email header.i=@stackoverflow.email header.b="r6EdTtiu"
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
    d=stackoverflow.email; 
    h=content-type:from:list-unsubscribe:mime-version:reply-to:subject:to; 
    s=s1; bh=/mAAZXhTNkMi6rIPclhuiiuHNlA=; b=r6EdTtiuqI384o5JhT7VyDj
    UsqzISLIx7B4NmH1KE8Imn5Gm+2F1uoIVrGVFjhgh6vcafdOttJchesgwbpOIB9L
    rsFtgaCkBfZHOiq9Md7Xdr9iKiJ3yjaw4D7lxq9H7ccc1SjDGbGx+hrfYFl/QX4s
    NbClO0f37LOVFlEwNoRk=
Received: by filter1270p1las1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter1270p1las1-14455-5D94D4FC-12
        2019-10-02 16:49:00.33677624 +0000 UTC m=+69003.745394183
Received: from NTg0MTE0MQ (ec2-100-24-43-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com [100.24.43.50])
    by ismtpd0014p1iad2.sendgrid.net (SG) with HTTP id LCICV5WWTrCL-RQYBFXhIw
    for <obfuscated@obfuscated.com>; Wed, 02 Oct 2019 16:49:00.238 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=5fa36584273123c694e86880080b7c8c4a41af1564eade29a698ea7a6e68
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 16:49:00 +0000 (UTC)
Feedback-ID: 1144188:814177:7013:iterable
From: "Cesar at Stack Overflow" <research@stackoverflow.email>
```

So the email comes from `stackoverflow.email` (not `stackoverflow.com`) originating on an AWS node via SendGrid...  sure looks phishy to me.

Is it?

Comment: Sorry, but anything promising free money for taking a survey has to clear a pretty high bar, such as being PGP (or GPG)-signed with a keypair I can verify.  Otherwise it gets tossed immediately.  I would have expected SO to know better.

Comment: It's not even free money. $45 for a 45 minute "meeting"? Anyway, FWIW [the IP of the domain seems to be](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.email) matching [with some other domains](http://reverseip.domaintools.com/search/?q=151.101.1.69) that are part of the SE network so at least that bit checks out. Still wouldn't click it though.

Comment: The domain name stackoverflow.email and the use of sendgrid + AWS is not suspicious and in line with previous mails, at least. If it's phishing, it's very well-researched phishing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there was a reasonable chance it was legit, but it feels so poorly thought out that I have no intention of clicking.