# User Research email from Stack Overflow: Calendly URL is not valid

Tags: support, email

I just received an email with the following content:

[image]

When I click the button I am redirected to https://calendly.com/cmanara/emailinterviews and the page looks like:

[image]

What is going on? Is this email really from SO? (I never received from them before.) If yes, what about the invalid URL? Will it be fixed soon?

Comment: Related: [Possible phishing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390035/2675154)

Comment: I received one of these today. For me, the link worked just fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not phishing, it's real and it will happen. You are seeing a not valid URL because we have already reached the maximum number of interviews we can do for this event.

I have been answering folks who emailed me 1:1 on it.

Thank you for asking and thanks for the many people interested in participating, the response has been great and we filled all slots up pretty quickly.

Comment: kudos for taking the time to attend to these issues amidst the firestorm that is on the site. You (and the rest of the team) have my heartfelt wishes.