# How would you respond to this long-term research invitation from SO?

Tags: discussion, user-experience, ux-research-time

Yesterday, I received an email from research@stackoverflow.email titled *Invitation: Help to shape a new Stack Overflow feature*. It basically offers me to provide feedback to help designing new stuff on SO.

As a starter: as most SO users, I understand that the first strength of the site is its community, and I am sure willing to help making it a better place. However - maybe because I am a rather fresh member (< 2 years) - some questions came to my mind after reading the email, and I thought I would share on Meta.

The mail goes like:

> We are about to kick off a long-term research project, and are looking for Stack Overflow users to be part of it. We are contacting you because you are an established, active member of the site and we'd love your opinions to help shape what we're working on.
>
> The project aims to find new ways to connect our users to the technologies they are interested in, and we will explore new forms of collaboration such as new content types, discussions, and group membership.
>
> We will be starting our research sessions in August, and ideally we would like to speak to you once per month from August to November (so a total of 4 sessions). Each session will last 60 minutes, and you will be compensated $60 per session, via gift card.
>
> During these sessions we will ask questions about how you currently use Stack Overflow, and get your opinions on new designs and ideas. All feedback will be used to inform product and design decisions.
>
> *[ ... less interesting stuff follows ...]*

Open questions:

- Does SO run this kind of project on a regular basis, or is this something new? There has been tensions between SO management and the community recently, is this some kind of response to that?
- If you ever participated in this, did you feel that it ended up being helpful? If not: do you think that there is a decent chance such a project would eventually be useful?
- How do you react to the fact that SO is willing to actually *pay* users to participate in improving the UX? I always thought as my involvement on SO as something I do for free, out of good-will and interest in the technology, so why would they want to compensate me now?
- In a nutshell: how would *you* respond to such invitation... and why?

Comment: Just in case anyone is questioning it, this is a real project. We've sent emails like this to several avid SO users based on recent activity, not necessarily tenure on the site. This is a mixture of frequent answerers, editors, commenters along with regular MSO users.

Comment: my mails from SO land promptly in  the spam box

Comment: The 60min sessions would be a no-deal from me

Comment: @KevinB: why is that?

Comment: 1st and foremost i value my free time and wouldn't want to commit that much of it to a resource i don't feel confident in, regardless of compensation... but also there are certain personalities I'd rather not come in contact with. It's just a source of stress/anxiety i'd rather not need to deal with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does SO run this kind of project on a regular basis, or is this something new? There has been tensions between SO management and the community recently, is this some kind of response to that?

Maybe not so regularly, but it's mentioned "only a few per year" on the [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

Also, searching on meta, there have been at least 4 researches being done:

- [UX research time! March 2019 and the user profile and settings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/ux-research-time-march-2019-and-the-user-profile-and-settings)
- [UX research time! May 2019 and the reputation system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384981/ux-research-time-may-2019-and-the-reputation-system)
- [UX research time! July 2019 and how people are learning and teaching code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387261/ux-research-time-july-2019-and-how-people-are-learning-and-teaching-code)
- [User Research email from Stack Overflow: Calendly URL is not valid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390048/user-research-email-from-stack-overflow-calendly-url-is-not-valid) (October 2019)

And additionally

- "Do people downvote their colleagues?" (April 2020, I received an invitation)
- "New ways to connect SO users to the technologies they are interested in" (this email, August-November 2020)

> If you ever participated in this, did you feel that it ended up being helpful? If not: do you think that there is a decent chance such a project would eventually be useful?

I've never participated in it personally, so I can't tell my experience, but previous meta posts might give insights for SO staff and also for the community.

> How do you react to the fact that SO is willing to actually pay users to participate in improving the UX? I always thought as my involvement on SO as something I do for free, out of good-will and interest in the technology, so why would they want to compensate me now?

I've seen research from outside SO and they also compensate their participants for taking their valuable time. The only research from SO I've been invited also stated a compensation, so I believe it's normal and even appreciated as a good-will.

> In a nutshell: how would you respond to such invitation... and why?

I'm honestly interested, but I declined in the end, not because I think it wouldn't be useful, just that I'm worried about communicating in English verbally over the internet with bad connection and microphone...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and especially for the links. Interesting to read the summaries of the researches. Although they are quite generic, it still feels like something useful. I am not uncomfortable speaking English, so I might want to give it a try!

Answer (score 17):

> Does SO run this kind of project on a regular basis, or is this something new? There has been tensions between SO management and the community recently, is this some kind of response to that?

I don't know if "regular" is the right word, but I've participated in a few over the past several years. I receive an email similar to the one you posted, select an available time from an open schedule and sign in (using Google Meet, I think). Depending on what the project was, it's been one on one conversations and group conversations either just me and a few people on the SE site or groups of users and groups of SE employees.

> If you ever participated in this, did you feel that it ended up being helpful? If not: do you think that there is a decent chance such a project would eventually be useful?

I've felt each were helpful. Different projects have been about different things. I've participated in some moderator specific projects. I've participated in from UX projects. "Useful" in this case does not mean implemented. I've expressed my unhappiness with at least one of the proposals. But, during that, it's been a very good conversation on *why*. I consider that useful.

I also feel that this is a great chance for anyone that is participating to have their voice heard. Each one I've been involved in has been well run.

> How do you react to the fact that SO is willing to actually pay users to participate in improving the UX? I always thought as my involvement on SO as something I do for free, out of good-will and interest in the technology, so why would they want to compensate me now?

I react no differently to this than I do to SO providing swag to users that reach certain reputation thresholds, holding occasional swag contests or any of the other ways they've provided material awards in the past. This sounds like a decent chunk of time to invest.

> In a nutshell: how would you respond to such invitation... and why?

Full disclosure - I received a very similar email and accepted. Why? Because it's interesting to see what's being proposed. It's useful to provide input, especially at such an early stage in a project. These are often at stages that an MSO/MSE post isn't even appropriate. It's just too early in the process. The conversations are engaging. If you have a question about why/how, they are more than happy to answer. It's a two way conversation. It's not just a "look at this wireframe...is it good or bad?" activity.

Additionally, as higher ranking members, we have a very different experience on SO than someone just joining. I'm sure you've read many of the blog posts/roadmaps/upcoming activities and seen they focus a lot of user retention and new user experience. This is an opportunity for you, as someone who has been retained and is not a new user, to offer your detailed thoughts.

Comment: Thanks. Now I feel like I should go for it, and hope that I will turn out useful somehow! Cheers.