# Validity of Feedback program with monetary compensation

Tags: support, email, survey

I recently received an email from *'Jose Santiago at Stack Overflow'* and *'research@stackoverflow.email'*, claiming to be from Stack Overflow, offering a $30 gift card in exchange for a 30-minute conversation about a new feature on the platform. The email provided details about the conversation and instructions on how to sign up. I want to clarify that I am not interested in the monetary compensation but I want to confirm if this is a legitimate research program from Stack Overflow.

I didn't think companies reached out to users personally for feedback with compensation. I also couldn't find any information about this program on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For the record, they have done paid research before, and that is their email domain (though, yes, it's one hell of a suspicious TLD). Assuming you can verify it's from them (read: that you're able to verify all the links redirect to official stack domains, that there isn't a sneaky reply to a wildly different domain, etc.), it's the real deal. You've presumably opted into research (settings -> edit email settings to verify), and you were picked at random from that pool

Comment: Related: [How would you respond to this long-term research invitation from SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399950/2602718) Note that this is an option [in your email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) (under the "Research" header).

Comment: Yes, this is legitimate, it's something SO has been doing for quite a while and SO certainly isn't the only company using this technique. I'd prefer more inclusive options for participating in this form of feedback

Comment: This is a common approach for gathering feedback and doing custdev. However, I've ignored that invitation because 1. SO/SE does not need to a face-to-face call to receive my feedback. 2. SO/SE itself does not have a built-in voice or video conferencing. All user communication and activities is built on a text-based Q/A approach. Now there is no place for such calls and conversations. So why would I want to participate in a face to face call? I'm accustomed to the current model and there is no place for such calls in it. Need my feedback? Just ask me a question.

Comment: If you are ever concerned about the validity of an email, *any* email, open up the source for the email and look at the headers for the sender. The IP address should match with the name given. If it looks strange, then it is probably a fake, especially if it comes from a foreign country when you were expecting a .com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes that's legitimate usually. I've participated in one of the user research sessions and can tell you I did receive the compensation.

Usually these research sessions involve more time than answering a simple survey, so a token compensation is given to participants for their time.

I can also confirm research@stackoverflow.email was the email from which I was invited to the feedback session, but remember some spam emails can fake the sender address. You do well in taking extra caution.

As other users have pointed out, you can opt out from receiving these emails by going to the Email Settings section and unticking the "Invitations" checkbox.

Finally, never give your banking account details or any other type of information, not even to the legit SO. In my case the reward was a coupon through a voucher platform, where I could pick a gift card of my choice without having to add any banking information.

However, you may be requested to sign an NDA about the contents of the research or an informed consent, and that's legit too.